# Error: browser.newPage: acceptDownloads: expected one of (accept|deny|internal-browser-default)

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have playwright automation setup and running test on browser stack.
playwright version 1.37.1

```
Error: browser.newPage: acceptDownloads: expected one of (accept|deny|internal-browser-default)

       at src/base/fixtures.ts:62

      60 |   page: async ({ browser }, use, testInfo) => {
      61 |     if (isBstack) {
    > 62 |       const bstackPage = await browser.newPage(testInfo.project.use);
         |                                        ^
      63 |       await Browserstack.setSessionName(bstackPage, testInfo);
      64 |       await Browserstack.annotateTest(bstackPage, testInfo);
      65 |       await use(bstackPage);

        at Object.page (/home/runner/work/vendor-portal-fe/vendor-portal-fe/playwright/src/base/fixtures.ts:62:40)
```

We have tried to add

```
acceptDownloads: true
```

for browser but it did not work.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve]. Please provide one so it's possible to help. What is `testInfo.project.use`? `browser.newPage()` accepts one optional argument: `options`. If `acceptDownloads` is provided in the `options` object, it's a [boolean according to the 1.39.0 docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browser#browser-new-context-option-accept-downloads). It's possible it changed in a recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Check the browserstack.playwrightVersion and clientPlaywrightVersion(locally installed version) and match the both. It will get resolved.
[PlaywrightIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8cb1.png)