# Browserstack Automate dashboard not registering Playwright tests after version update

Tags: playwright, browserstack

When running Playwright tests with Browserstack integration, I have been getting the error

> browser.newPage: acceptDownloads: expected one of (accept|deny|internal-browser-default)"

This was being thrown in all tests, which did not include download functionality.

According to an answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77288070/error-browser-newpage-acceptdownloads-expected-one-of-acceptdenyinternal-b), this should be solved by ensuring that the client and Browserstack Playwright versions are the same.

I updated my local Playwright version to 1.38.1 accordingly (listed as a supported version [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/playwright/browsers-and-os)), and while I’m no longer getting the error, my Browserstack automate dashboard is no longer logging any of my tests. The same happened when updating the local Playwright version to 1.39.0.

How can I log tests in v1.39.0? Or resolve the error otherwise, without upgrading?

Comment: Please confirm if you are using these O.S. and Browser version combinations:
Windows: 10, 11

Mac OS: Ventura, Monterey, Big Sur, Catalina

WebKit v17.4
Mozilla Firefox v118.0
Chromium v119.0

Comment: @grandEL-dsouza yes I'm using MacOS Ventura and the aforementioned versions of browsers, as cross checked in the link I provided. If I didn't install those browser versions when I updated Playwright then I'd get an error message pointing that out.....?